# Filter resources maven-shade-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to filter the resources included in my jar. I'm using shade-maven-plugin and this one is adding all the resources of all my dependencies into my generated jar, I only want to be included my project resources.

Here is my pom definition:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>es.app.applet.MyApplet</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I tried to add the next filter to remove all the resources, and then add another filter adding only my artifactID resources, but it doesn't work.

```
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>resources/*.*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter> <filter>
                        <artifact>my.groupId:my.artifactId</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>resources/*.*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
```

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: looks fair , didn't your filter keep your ressources?

Answer (score 2):

This is because filter includes happen before filter excludes.

With your code you are including you "my.groupId:my.artifactId" -> resources/*.*

But aterwards you are excluding all "resources/*.*"

From the original [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) :

> From a logical perspective, includes are processed before excludes,
>   thus it's possible to use an include to collect a set of files from
>   the archive then use excludes to further reduce the set.